# CSS3 & HTML5 ; transition Doesnt work

Tags: html, css, properties, transition, duration

im doing something on HTML,CSS and transition-property, transition-duration, transition-timing-function properties arent work on my project.  I used every -webkit- , -moz-, -o- and others not work. I did uninstall the Google Chrome and I installed it again but dont work. My codes:

index.php:

```
<?php

include "function/baglanti.php";

?>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Deneme | Anasayfa</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="den">sshshsh</div>

</body>

</html>
```

main.css:

```
#den
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#den:hover
{
    width: 200px;
    transition: width 0.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: Of course it works, so how does it not work for you?

Comment: The transition is working but think like that;
The box witdth is 100 when im not hover the box.
But when i hover the box its 200px in 0.5s animation. But when i focus other sides the box's width is being 100px in 0.00001milisec. The back transition is not working; transition is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the transition to work both ways, move the `transition` property to the `#den` rule

```css
#den
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    transition: width 0.5s linear;     /*  moved it here and it work both ways  */
}

#den:hover
{
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="den">sshshsh</div>
```

Comment: The codes working in stackowerflow, but they arent working in my wampserver project :/

Comment: @MuhammedÇağlarTUFAN Please note that I _moved_ the `transition` property

Comment: No, i didnt forget :(

Comment: @MuhammedÇağlarTUFAN Well, since this work, you need to post more code so we can see what might be causing that to not work

Comment: yes its work now. Sorry i wasnt save the codes :P Thank u my friend !!!